# Element exceeds containing master element ending

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, aac

I am using ffmpeg to a mkv to dash format file using the following:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -c:v copy -c:a aac -sn -f dash test.mpd
```

then will print some error, and some audio segment files will lost some times, and the player hasn't any sound. The Error is:

```
Element at 0xe35c18f ending at 0x2ebfcc018 exceeds containing master element ending at 0xe3b7217
```

When changing format to libvorbis, still has this error, and player hasn't sound.

---

My env is:
Mac(m1) + ffmpeg(6.0)